# C# Outlook Interop: Is there a way to get notified on new calender item creation?

Tags: c#, outlook

Outlook Interop has these two events:

1. `new Application().NewMail`
2. `new Application().NewMailEx`

But I can't find the equivalent for calender item creation events. Is polling the only way to get notified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Calendar folder (retrieved using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)`).